# How to consume a soap web service in WSO2 Integration Studio 8.1.0 by using call mediator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I have a soap web service with extension wsdl. So ı want to call mediator this soap endpoint. How is it work wso2 integration studio ?

Comment: Do you want to do a SOAP call just with the WSDL?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you can achieve this is, by first adding your SOAP endpoint as a `WSDL Endpoint` to the project, and then using it in the `Call` mediator.

Check the below URLs:

- https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/examples/endpoint_examples/using-wsdl-endpoints/
- https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/creating-artifacts/creating-endpoints/